# Trying to append data they show error 'dict' object has no attribute 'append'

Tags: python, json, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

They show me error that `AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'append'` how to handle these error when trying to append the data I am creating a loop in order to append continuously values from user input to a dictionary but i am getting this error is any method to show solve these error this is page link https://www.nationalhardwareshow.com/en-us/attend/exhibitor-list.html:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json
import pandas as pd
headers = {
    'Accept-Language': 'en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8,pt;q=0.7',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'Origin': 'https://www.nationalhardwareshow.com',
    'Referer': 'https://www.nationalhardwareshow.com/',
    'Sec-Fetch-Dest': 'empty',
    'Sec-Fetch-Mode': 'cors',
    'Sec-Fetch-Site': 'cross-site',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/103.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
    'accept': 'application/json',
    'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'sec-ch-ua': '".Not/A)Brand";v="99", "Google Chrome";v="103", "Chromium";v="103"',
    'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
    'sec-ch-ua-platform': '"Windows"',
}
base_url='https://api.reedexpo.com/v1/organisations/'

params = {
    'x-algolia-agent': 'Algolia for vanilla JavaScript 3.27.1',
    'x-algolia-application-id': 'XD0U5M6Y4R',
    'x-algolia-api-key': 'd5cd7d4ec26134ff4a34d736a7f9ad47',
}

data = '{"params":"query=&page=0&facetFilters=&optionalFilters=%5B%5D"}'

resp = requests.post('https://xd0u5m6y4r-3.algolianet.com/1/indexes/event-edition-eve-e6b1ae25-5b9f-457b-83b3-335667332366_en-us/query', params=params, headers=headers, data=data).json()
productlinks=[]
for item in resp['hits']:
    url=base_url+item['organisationGuid']+"/exhibiting-organisations?eventEditionId="+item['eventEditionExternalId']
    productlinks.append(url)
    
data=[]   
for link in productlinks:
    headers = {"x-clientid": "uhQVcmxLwXAjVtVpTvoerERiZSsNz0om"}
    data = requests.get(link, headers=headers).json()
    wev={}
    for t in data["_embedded"]:
        name=t['companyName']
        wev['name']=name
        email=t['email']
        wev['Email']=email
        telephone=t["phone"]
        wev['Telephone']=telephone
        link=t['website']
        wev['link']=link
        d=t["multilingual"]
        for u in d:
           k=u["address"]
           wev['address']=k
           n=u["representedBrands"]
           wev['brand']=n
           
           data.append(wev)
        
df=pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)
```

Comment: you're using `data` to hold different types of content. it makes up for confusing code. you should review your code and use different variables for different things. in `for link in productlinks:` you rewrite `data`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is that you initialise `data` as a list and reassign to a `dict` data structure. Use different variables for different purposes instead:

```py
store = []
for link in productlinks:
    data = requests.get("...").json()
    # process data ...
    store.append(data)

df = pd.DataFrame(store)
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally speeking, in order to add a new element to a python dict, you should use:

```
old_dict  = {}
old_dict["key_name"] = 42
```

"key_name" can also be an other type. You have to have a key before "appending" something to a dictionary.